# calling master page jquery function from content page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Jquery function on master page which i am trying to call on button click event of contant page (from code behind) but getting error message

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'notification' is undefined

I have tried different things but no luck so far.

If i put the following tag on content aspx page then it calls the notification method but some how its not working when calling from code behind.

```
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="notification('success', 'This is a <strong>success</strong> message.');">Success</a>
```

Content page button control is in updatePanel. Don't if it is causing any problems.

**master page jquery function**

```
function notification(type, title, message) {
        if (type == 'success') {
            Command: toastr["success"](message, title)
            //toastr.success(title,message);
        } else if (type == 'error') {
            toastr.error(message, 'Error');
        } else if (type == 'warning') {
            toastr.warning(message, 'Warning');
        } else {
            toastr.info(message, 'Information');
        }
    }
```

**Master page code behind function**

```
Public Sub ShowNotification(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, ByVal type As NotificationType, ByVal title As String, ByVal message As String)
    Dim notifyType As String = ""
    Select Case type
        Case NotificationType.Success
            notifyType = "success"
        Case NotificationType.Erorr
            notifyType = "error"
        Case NotificationType.Info
            notifyType = "info"
        Case NotificationType.Warning
            notifyType = "warning"
    End Select

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(TryCast(sender, Control), Me.GetType(), "Notify", "notification('" + notifyType + "' , '" + title + "','" + message + "');", True)
End Sub
```

**Contant Page code behind function**

calling master page function.

```
 TryCast(Me.Page.Master, amis).ShowNotification(sender, e, amis.NotificationType.Success, "email sent...", "")
```

Comment: Is there any other code that interacts with this method in other places at the same request, like other events that happen after the click (like prerender)?

Comment: there is no pre render but i forgot to mention that content button is in updatepanel.

Comment: Please, add this information to the question. It's vital.

Comment: thanks. i have added that in my question.

Comment: i have come up with an idea to have two shared functions in the notification class RegisterNotificationScript() and DisplayMessage(). On page load (if not ispostback) event i can call RegisterNotificationScript() to add jquery function on page and then i can call it whenever it is needed on the same page by calling DisplayMessage() function. I have just tested this and works fine but i don't know if this is a professional way of doing it.

Comment: Good. Its a perfectly acceptable way. You can even post it as an answer and accept it.